# Variable framerate with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-arguments, framerate

Let's suppose that I have 5 images with the respective delays between each image:

1. 60ms;
2. 54ms;
3. 70ms;
4. 23ms;
5. 40ms;

How can I tell `FFmpeg` that information?

Comment: A more recent answer to this question in [How do I render a video from a list of time-stamped images?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72442310/1670156)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `-concat` option.
It's basically a text file with the name and duration of each input image.

Comment: But this doesn't actually work, because concat files have a [hard-coded granularity](https://superuser.com/a/1337998/416032) of 25fps (1/25=40ms), so most of the durations in the question would be rounded to the nearest 40ms, and produce a (mostly) constant framerate video.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the multiple tools method shown at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086775/5726027, it can be done through a single long command as well.

```
ffmpeg -i a1.jpg -i a2.jpg -i a3.jpg -i a4.jpg -i a5.jpg
       -filter_complex
        "[1]settb=1/1000,setpts=PTS+0.06/TB[b];
         [2]settb=1/1000,setpts=PTS+0.054/TB[c];
         [3]settb=1/1000,setpts=PTS+0.07/TB[d];
         [4]split[4a][4b];
         [4a]settb=1/1000,setpts=PTS+0.023/TB[e];
         [4b]settb=1/1000,setpts=PTS+0.04/TB[f];
         [0][b][c][d][e][f]concat=n=6"
       -vsync vfr -r 1000 -video_track_timescale 1000 vt.mp4
```

For each image except the first, timebase and timestamp filters are applied. Since you need millisecond accuracy, timebase is set to 1/1000 sec = 1 millisecond. Then the setpts adds the required delay (in seconds). Since I believe the very last frame of the video has, in effect, the default duration as determined by the codec frame rate, the very last image has to be duplicated. The first copy is set the PTS value as per its delay, and the second has its PTS set to the intended duration of the last image.

Comment: I'm planning to add ffmpeg as an option to encode recordings, by the looks of it, a small recording (500 frames) would take a lot of space, isn`t there any other way? Maybe zoompan filter it`s less verbose.

Comment: What are you recording?

Comment: The screen, webcam, or simple images as input.

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about VFR. x264 is very good at storing similar frames compactly. It stores identical frames in about 30-40 bytes.

Comment: Yes, but it's not always a 10ms difference, if the user selects 1 second of delay, for example...

Comment: For 1 second delay, that's 24 duplicate frames, so **~800 bytes** to store.