# How to generate a frame-accurate concat file image sequence overlay in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images, overlay

I am using a `concat.txt` file that looks like:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 000001.png #13-24 0.433767-0.834167
duration 0.4004
file 000002.png #25-35 0.834167-1.2012
duration 0.367033
file 000003.png
...
```

And the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.VOB -itsoffset 0.433767 -i concat.txt -filter_complex "[0]overlay=eof_action=pass,showinfo;[1]showinfo" -c:a copy output.VOB
```

This is an image sequence overlay that uses a concat file.

This is my FFmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
```

The problem I'm having is that I'd like the overlay to be frame-accurate: The first image should overlay frames 13-24, the second overlays frames 25-35, etc.

I have the exact `pts_time` for each frame (from showinfo), and have set the durations accordingly, but cannot get the overlays to start/end at the desired frames (by playing with the durations, I can only manage one frame too early, or one too late).

A hint comes from the showinfo output:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x564719ed1600] config in time_base: 1/90000, frame_rate: 30000/1001
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x564719ed1600] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x564719ed1dc0] config in time_base: 1/25, frame_rate: 25/1
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x564719ed1dc0] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x564719ed1dc0] n:   0 pts:     11 pts_time:0.44    pos:        0 fmt:rgb24 sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:F8CA2959 plane_checksum:[F8CA2959] mean:[63] stdev:[35.9]
```

The video (input.VOB) is a 29.97fps stream, while the overlay is set to the [default 25fps](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/13074).

Since durations are set manually, I think the `frame_rate` is not the actual problem, but the [`time_base`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/1670156) next to it: 1/25.  The first image in the overlay stream has its start time (0.433767) rounded to the nearest 1/25th (0.44), one frame too late. The same happens with other images:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:  24 pts:  72072 pts_time:0.8008  pos:   301070 fmt:yuv420p sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:44EFD0BE plane_checksum:[17B5BDB9 3C4A8674 83098C82] mean:[67 138 118] stdev:[26.4 5.6 3.1]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:  25 pts:  75075 pts_time:0.834167 pos:   313358 fmt:yuv420p sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:44EFD0BE plane_checksum:[17B5BDB9 3C4A8674 83098C82] mean:[67 138 118] stdev:[26.4 5.6 3.1]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:   1 pts:     21 pts_time:0.84    pos:        0 fmt:rgb24 sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:C47D9BDA plane_checksum:[C47D9BDA] mean:[63] stdev:[36.3]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:  26 pts:  78078 pts_time:0.867533 pos:   315406 fmt:yuv420p sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:29E90C18 plane_checksum:[A845EC05 E0C99215 FFD58DE0] mean:[67 138 118] stdev:[26.6 5.8 3.3]
...
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:  35 pts: 105105 pts_time:1.16783 pos:   354318 fmt:yuv420p sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:29E90C18 plane_checksum:[A845EC05 E0C99215 FFD58DE0] mean:[67 138 118] stdev:[26.6 5.8 3.3]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:   2 pts:     30 pts_time:1.2     pos:        0 fmt:rgb24 sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:7A31E90F plane_checksum:[7A31E90F] mean:[64] stdev:[36.7]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55c01673f600] n:  36 pts: 108108 pts_time:1.2012  pos:   358414 fmt:yuv420p sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:6A1DCE13 plane_checksum:[DC94840F 6D0ED2E5 F82E7710] mean:[69 138 118] stdev:[27.0 5.8 3.3]
```

rounded to the nearest 1/25th.  I tried adding `[1]settb=expr=1/90000`, and this resulted in the time_base matching the input video as desired, but had no effect on the `pts_time` granularity of the overlay (though notice how the `pts` went from 11 to 39600):

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55ffb8a06940] config in time_base: 1/90000, frame_rate: 30000/1001
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x55ffb8a06940] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_3 @ 0x55ffb8a07780] config in time_base: 1/90000, frame_rate: 25/1
[Parsed_showinfo_3 @ 0x55ffb8a07780] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_3 @ 0x55ffb8a07780] n:   0 pts:  39600 pts_time:0.44    pos:        0 fmt:rgb24 sar:8/9 s:720x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:F8CA2959 plane_checksum:[F8CA2959] mean:[63] stdev:[35.9]
```

Same deal with the subsequent images. Not sure where to go from here.

Is it possible to get greater granularity than 1/25th of a second in an image overlay using a concat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to this limitation.

**What is the problem?**

As mentioned in [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1337998/416032) by one of the developers of ffmpeg, the concat image sequence framerate is hard-coded:

> ... each image is assigned the default framerate of 25 fps. At this
> time, this can't be changed.

I confirmed this by running:

```
ffmpeg -i concat.txt -vf fps=250,showinfo concat.mkv
```

and the frame durations round to the nearest 1/25=0.04s even when a granularity of 1/250 is available in the output:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0xd00b60] config in time_base: 1/250, frame_rate: 250/1
```

**What is the workaround?**

The concat file durations can be multiplied by some factor that maintains granularity above 25fps, and then that same factor can be divided out when generating the overlay.

A convenient factor to use is the [timescale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/1670156).  Multiplying timestamps by the timescale, we get ... their respective `pts` values, so we can just use those instead.  Since `pts` values are integers, they can also safely be divided by 25.  Using the sample concat file above, we get:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 000001.png #13-24 0.433767-0.834167
duration 1441.44 # 0.4004 * 90000 = 36036 (pts) /25
file 000002.png #25-35 0.834167-1.2012
duration 1321.32 # 0.367033 * 90000 = 33033 (pts) /25
file 000003.png #36
...
```

And then the overlay command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.VOB -i concat.txt -filter_complex "[1]settb=1/90000,setpts=39039+PTS*25/90000[o];[0:v:0][o]overlay=eof_action=pass" -c:a copy -vsync passthrough output.VOB
```

Notice that `-itsoffset` has been moved into the filter (0.433767s pts=39039), and then the precise timestamp is extracted by factoring back out the timescale and also the extra 25 we divided by earlier.